# Are $S^2\times S^1$ and $S^3$ homeomorphic to each other

Tags: hopf-fibration

I was trying to visualize the 3-sphere, $S^3$.

One way is with the help of hopf fibration, as there is a fibre bundle with total space being $S^3$,
$$S^1 \hookrightarrow S^3 \rightarrow S^2$$
and this can be thought of as a $S^1$ fiber over $S^2$. The way I visualize a fibre is like drawing the fiber at each point of the base space, so if we have the base space as $S^1$, a circle, and an $S^1$ fiber is thought of as attaching each point of the circle another circle. If this is done in such a way as is usually represented in lectures, what we get is a torus, $T^2$. And also, we know that a 2-torus is nothing but the cartesian product of two circles, i.e. $S^1\times S^1$.

I tend to extend this way of thinking and tend to construct a 3-sphere as the cartesian product of a 2-sphere and a 1-sphere.

My doubt is that whether this way of thinking is right or not. Or is $S^2\times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$

Comment: They are not homeomorphic, since they have different homologies.

Comment: The point with fibrations is that they are only locally like a product. For example, if $I$ is the standard interval, then the Moebius strip $M$ is a fibration $I \hookrightarrow M \to S^1$, but this doesn't mean $M = S^1 \times I$.

Comment: They are not homemorphic, since the surgery knot of $S^2 \times S^1$ in $S^3$ is the unknot, but this is not Kirby equivalent to the surgery knot of $S^3$, which is empty.

Comment: The probability that someone who cannot distinguish these two spaces can use their descriptions as the result of surgeries to do that is -0.73

Comment: @JoMo I got it, loosely speaking there will be twist when looking  globally in the case of Mobius, otherwise it is a cylinder, and a cylider is obviously not homeomorphic to a mobius.

Comment: I have to look for what a surgery knot is.. do you have any reference to suggest for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these are not homeomorphic. You can see this by comparing their fundamental groups. The fundamental group of $ S^{3} $ is trivial, so $\pi_1(S^3)=0 $ because $ S^{3} $ is simply connected. Meanwhile $\pi_1(S^2 \times S^1) = \pi_1(S^2) \times \pi_1(S^1) = 0 \times \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: Yeah, this calculation makes it clear. But how is connectedness related to the fundamental group explicitly? I mean apart from an indicator for simply connectedness, is there a general relation

Comment: So generally speaking the choice of a "base point" matters when working with fundamental group, however, in path connected spaces the fundamental group is isomorphic for all choices of base point. Path + trivial fundamental group is one definition of simply connected.

Comment: what is the defintion for doubly connected or in general multiply connected.. and how is it different from "n-connected", I mean how are  2-connected and doubly connected different?